# Are all the subgraphs of K5 planar?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Given the graph is a K5.

Are all its subgraphs planar? A visual analysis tells me so, but then again I don't know if there's any mathematical way to proof this.

Comment: Based on this [quora link](https://www.quora.com/Are-all-the-subgraphs-of-K5-planar-graph-theory-planar-graphs-and-math/answer/Michael-Harrison-482), you can also use the [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem#Statement). Since the **proper** subgraphs of $K_5$ have at most 5 vertices (can't be  homeomorphic to $K_{3,3}$) and can't be  homeomorphic to $K_{5}$ by [subdivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing) which will add at least one more vertex. So they are planar.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be the graph that results when you delete one edge from $K_5$; every proper subgraph of $K_5$ is a subgraph of $G$, and you can exhibit an embedding of $G$ in the plane, so all proper subgraphs of $K_5$ must be planar.

Comment: Thanks! I created a proper subgraph as you said and changed the shape of said G subgraph of K5. The graph G is planar thus its subgraphs are also planar. Thank you!

Comment: @WildTarzan: You’re welcome!